# optimize the expected value of a process

Tags: probability, algorithms

There are $a_i$ balls painted with number $i$. For example if we have balls painted with 1,1,1,3,2.
we have $a_1 = 3$, $a_2=1$, $a_3=1$. In total there are $m$ balls painted with number $1,\ldots,n$.

There are $n$ bins. Bin $B_i$ can only contain balls numbered $j$, where $j\leq i$.

Each $B_i$ is associated with a weight $w_i$. $w_i\geq w_j$ if $i\leq j$. The bins have a capacity of $c_i$. $c_i\leq c_j$ if $i\leq j$.

Initially there is 1 ball in $B_1$. The non-empty bin is called the current bin.

Whenever bin $B_i$ is filled(the amount of balls reached the capacity), remove all the balls from $B_i$ and put them in $B_{i+1}$. So there will be only one non-empty bin.

$t_0$ and $k$ are given constants.

We do the following process at step i:

> If $t_i=0$, then terminate and return $bw$, where $b$ is the number of balls in
>   the current bin, and $w$
>   is the weight of the current bin.
>
> Else randomly choose $t_ik$ balls(include the ones in the bin). Return the
>   ones painted with higher number than the current bin and the ones already in the bin, and put the rest
>   in the current bin. The number of newly added balls in this step is $t_{i+1}$.

Intuitively, each ball is randomly attached to $k$ other balls. Putting one in the bin, it will try to "drag" $k$ other balls into the bin. The ball can only "drag" another ball once. The connection breaks afterwards.

The question is:

Given $a_i$, $w_i$, $t_0$ and $k$, compute the set of $c_i$ that maximize the expected return.

I can brute force all possible $c_i$ and see which one turns out the best, but there are $O(m^n)$ possibilities.

The model is so simple I can't help to think is there a simple relation between these variables.

If not, are there faster algorithms than naively try everything?

Comment: Just to be clear: is $t_{i+1}$ the difference between the number of usable balls added at step $i$ and the number of usable balls at the previous step, or is it the number of usable balls added at step $i$?

Comment: it's the number of usable balls added at step i. I will change it to make it clear.

Comment: "The model is so simple I can't help to think is there a simple relation between these variables." I dare to disagree. In fact, by the time I'd reached that sentence I was thinking quite the opposite. Also you might want to add some motivation for considering this particular problem; it seems like a rather arbitrary construction to me.